# Activate tezos generated account (sk => secret)

Tags: tezos-client, account, eztz, cryptography, encrypted

I'm trying to generate an account keys based on the Eztz lib and I got the following result:

```
{
  "mnemonic": [
    "cruel",
    "announce",
    "mimic",
    "budget",
    "crouch",
    "frequent",
    "regret",
    "color",
    "relief",
    "eye",
    "ritual",
    "tree",
    "this",
    "wolf",
    "wool"
  ],
  "sk": "edskRh1xKGZLr8cUUYDP3wwP8CqbPGVP3ifTSFgCSp7bCdW3pexixMh2WD6c9BZdqLWQPnJ6VtYCQDu55LaAtE12H6spcnTfDX",
  "pkh": "tz1iuxhk93Fozqbb1D2uq9GERZMNEVw6hBdu",
}
```

When I want to activate the account I need to pass in secret field something like

> "4cbdfea69cb91f305263cf66b22518f222693be8"

(as faucet's result), so how can I get the faucet secret form the sk generated.

So, in conclusion, what kind of encryption/decryption to take to pass from

> sk: "edskRh1xKGZLr8cUUYDP3wwP8CqbPGVP3ifTSFgCSp7bCdW3pexixMh2WD6c9BZdqLWQPnJ6VtYCQDu55LaAtE12H6spcnTfDX"

to

> secret: "4cbdfea69cb91f305263cf66b22518f222693be8"

Comment: What do you mean with activate account?

Comment: Do you have a reference to the eztz functions you are trying to use?

Comment: 1. A transaction with kind "kind": "activate_account"

2. Didn't get it, sorry, what you mean by **reference to the eztz functions you are trying to use**?

Comment: You can activate this account by sending some tez from another account (e.g. faucet)

Comment: Yes, of course but the goal is to activate an account even if it's empty.